# pl sql How to make my code less

Tags: if-statement, plsql, sql-update, procedure

Can anyone help me to make my code less? (If you can notice to both if-elsif statements I make the same Select.. so I wish there was a way to make this select once. and update with 1 or 0 depending on the pilot_action).
Below its my code.

```
create or replace
PROCEDURE F_16 (TRK_ID NUMBER, pilot_action NUMBER) IS
BEGIN
  BEGIN 

    IF pilot_action=0 THEN
          UPDATE "ControlTow"
          SET "Intention"=0
          WHERE "Id" IN (              
          SELECT "Id" FROM "ControlTow" WHERE "Id"=TRK_ID );

    ELSIF pilot_action=1 THEN
          UPDATE "ControlTow"
          SET "Intention"=1        
          WHERE "Id" IN (
          SELECT "Id" FROM "ControlTow" WHERE "Id"=TRK_ID );
       END IF;
  EXCEPTION
    WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN dbms_output.put_line('False Alarm');
  COMMIT;  
  END;    
END F_16;
```

thank you , in advance.

Comment: This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network: https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you seem to be assigning `pilot_action` to `Intention`, I would do following:

```
create or replace
PROCEDURE F_16 (TRK_ID NUMBER, pilot_action NUMBER) IS
BEGIN
  BEGIN 

    IF pilot_action IN (0, 1) THEN
       -- if the only condition in subselect is the ID then use it directly
       UPDATE "ControlTow"
          SET "Intention"= pilot_action
        WHERE "Id"=TRK_ID;
       -- if there are more conditions than just the ID then subselect may be the way to go 
       --(hard to say without more information)
       -- WHERE "Id" IN (              
       --   SELECT "Id" FROM "ControlTow" WHERE "Id"=TRK_ID AND ... )
    ELSE
      Null; -- do whatever you need in this case. Raise exception?
    END IF;
  EXCEPTION
    WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN dbms_output.put_line('False Alarm');
    COMMIT;  
  END;    
END F_16;
```

**EDIT**: As @user272735 said, there was room for more improvement on the code. Specifically rewriting the `if` condition to use `in` and simplifying the `where` clause (supposing `Id` is really the only condition to select rows to be updated).

Answer (score 2):

Your code has several issues I have addressed in the comments below. Note that transaction management is not discussed as it's not clear based on the question when `commit`/`rollback` should take place.

```
-- #1 use of explicit parameter mode
create or replace procedure f_16(p_trk_id in number, p_pilot_action in number) is
begin
  -- #2 use of in
  if p_pilot_action in (0, 1)
  then
    -- #3 unnecessary subquery removed
    update controltow
       set intention = p_pilot_action
     where id = p_trk_id;

    -- #4 use pl/sql implicit cursor attribute to check the number of affected rows
    if sql%rowcount = 0
    then
      dbms_output.put_line('false alarm');
    end if;
  end if;
end;
```

Comment: thanks for the concern my friend but @Guillems solution is working and I will go with that. :)

Comment: @TakisMakis You're welcome to write as inferior code as you like ;) However the other readers should note the accepted answer might not be "the most correct" (with some definition of "correct") answer.

Comment: ok.. I will have it in my mind.. but for the record the line where Guillem says "  SET "Intention"= pilot_action  " solve my problem. Thats all.

Comment: your answer is working too but i have a trouble at   if sql%rowcount = 0
    then
      dbms_output.put_line('false alarm');

Comment: @user272735, +1, you're right about both the `where` condition (unless there are more conditions in the subselect that the OP didnt include in the questions) and the `in` condition (too few coffeine when I answered...) . As for the checking of the affected rows, it might be interesting or not depending on what the OP needs.